# Error using objects and outlets in Views

Tags: connection, xamarin.ios, outlet

I have declared an UIViewController to show more views because my program needs multiple views. OK everything is ok and another pages will load when i need but when i add outlets (in vies) to Files Owner (for example a button). application wont work, and will quit immediately.

I have described my issue complete in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsx-72TP2m8

Thanks and Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the best described question I have seen so far!

The problem is that you are trying to force a `UIViewController` to load a XIB whose file owner is of type `SOME`. Although `SOME` inherits `UIViewController`, the outlet connections (let's say variables) belong to `SOME`. So the runtime tries to connect the outlets from the XIB, to the `UIViewController` instance. This is why you are getting an NSUnknownKeyException.

The best thing to do is:

```
SOME homePage = new SOME();
```

instead of `UIViewController homePage = new UIViewController("SOME", null);`.

Remember, it is `SOME`'s constructor **(nibName, bundle)** you need, not `UIViewController`'s.

Comment: Hi, your answer is awesome. thank you! Actually you are true and i have done what you told me and then it works without any problem.